# Query column A, order by B - is index needed if A and B together are the PK?

Tags: index

I have a table (in Postgresql) which has a primary key on columns a and b. I want to do a query:

```
select * from table where a='XXX' order by b;
```

Does the existing primary key serve to help with the performance of that query?

Can I improve performance by making one or more other indexes eg. an index on a and/or an index on b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you already have an index on `(a, b)` and the PK constraint means you do, then you don't need anything else for this query.

Separate indexes on `(a)` and `(b)` would not be useful.

The only thing that might be better than the index on (a, b) would be a covering index. Say you have a query with only `SELECT b, c, d` columns in the select list while the table has some 10+ columns. Then, an index on `(a, b) INCLUDE (c, d)` or in lack of that on `(a, b, c, d)` would be much narrower than the table and would suit the query perfectly. It would result in a better query plan (only an inde seek, no access to the table needed), on the expense of course that you have an additional index targeted for the specific query.

Comment: Some additional info for the second part: "A multicolumn B-tree index can be used with query conditions that involve any subset of the index's columns" (from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/indexes-multicolumn.html ). So you even do not need to specify all columns from the index and the index should still be used.